# Zusammengesetztes Prädikat

Tags: sentence-structure

Guten Tag,

kann mir bitte jemand sagen, wo in den folgenden Sätzen das Prädikat ist? Am besten mit einer kurzen Erklärung (evtl. Verweis auf irgendein Standardregelwerk). Danke!

1. Ich kann nicht schwimmen.
2. Schwimmen kann ich nicht.
3. Ich habe die Tasse fallen lassen.
4. Ich will spazieren gehen.

Insbesondere die ersten zwei Fälle sind für mich unklar. Ich habe gelernt, dass das Prädikat an zweiter Stelle im Satz stehen soll. Wenn das Prädikat im ersten Satz "kann nicht schwimmen" ist, dann müsste das Prädikat im zweiten Satz "Schwimmen kann nicht" sein, aber dann würde das Prädikat an erster Stelle im Satz stehen.

Danke!

Comment: Hausaufgabe? Unabhängig davon: Es gibt verschiedene Prädikatsbegriffe (semantisch oder syntaktisch, weiter oder enger). Ohne zu wissen, welcher Prädikatsbegriff zugrunde gelegt wird, ist die Beantwortung der Frage nicht sinnvoll.

Comment: Nein, keine Hausaufgabe, sondern Verständnisfrage. Über die verschiedenen Prädikatsbegriffe weiß ich bisher nichts. Ich dachte, es ist ein grammatikalischer Begriff, der eindeutig definiert ist.

Answer (score 2):

Ein Prädikat besteht im einfachsten Fall nur aus einem *konjugierten Verb*.

> Du gehst.
> Sie schweigen.
> Ich bin ein Berliner.

Wenn das Prädikat aus mehreren Teilen besteht, gibt es trotzdem genau ein konjugiertes Verb (aka *finites Verb*), das in Kongruenz (1./2./3. Person, Einzahl oder Mehrzahl) zum Subjekt steht. In dem Fall ist das oft ein Hilfsverb wie können, werden, haben, sein, mögen, müssen ...

Dieses finite Verb, egal ob Hilfsverb oder nicht, steht im Hauptsatz an zweiter Stelle, egal wo die anderen Teile des Prädikats stehen. Das heißt, es steht nach dem ersten Satzteil -- der durchaus auch aus mehreren Wörtern bestehen kann.

> Ich ***kann*** nicht *schwimmen*.
> *Schwimmen* ***kann*** ich nicht.
> Ich ***habe*** die Tasse *fallen lassen*.
> Ich ***will** spazieren gehen*.

Mehr Beispiele:

> Morgen früh ***werden*** wir *schwimmen üben müssen*.
> Da ***hat*** sie dich aber ganz schön gelinkt!
> Dich ***mag*** ich ja ganz besonders!
> Einem guten Cocktail ***würde*** ich mich jetzt nicht *verweigern*.
> Dass er nicht gerne schwimmt, ***wusste*** ich schon immer.

(Im letzten Fall nimmt der Nebensatz als Objekt die erste Stelle ein.)

Mehr zu den verschiedenen Prädikatsbegriffen, die David Vogt angesprochen hat:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikat_(Grammatik)

Comment: Danke für die Erläuterungen und Beispiele. Was ist nun das Prädikat im Sat "Schwimmen kann ich nicht."?

Comment: @fml2: ich habe das Prädikat überall kursiv markiert, also in dem Fall "Schwimmen kann". es besteht aus dem, was zum zusammengesetzten Verb gehört. "Ich" ist das Subjekt, "nicht" ist ein Negationspartikel. Das finite Verb ist "kann", deshalb steht es an zweiter Stelle, hier nach einen weiteren Bestandteil des Prädikats. Ähnlich: "*Geputzt habe* ich schon.", "*Schwimmen können sollte* möglichst jeder."

Comment: Herzlichen Dank! Mich hat irritiert, dass das Wort "Schwimmen" ganz vorne steht. Ich habe gelesen, dass bei der "Prädikatsklammer" das Infinitiv am Ende des Satzes stehen soll.

Comment: Normalerweise stimmt das ja auch. Zur Betonung kann man im Deutschen aber Satzteile nach vorne holen. Satzteile kann man im Deutschen aber zur Betonung nach vorne holen. Nach vorne holen kann man aber im Deutschen Satzteile zur Betonung. Im Deutschen kann man aber zur Betonung Satzteile nach vorne holen. Nur das finite Verb nicht.